# Submenus of main menu don't show up (drupal)

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, submenu, theming

I just started to work with drupal, I'm trying to create a drop down submenu from the main menu, however it doesn't show up. Not because I misconfigured something (I think). 
Can anybody tell me why this is the case?

I'm using the Bootstrap theme, i also tried others.

I have checked "Show as expanded" for parent menu item in main menu also.

Thanks,

Comment: Finally i used Nice Menus module, and edit the theme's page.tpl.php file.
This Video tutorial helped me a lot >> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PxCUbQgNDY
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi This can be done using nice menu irrespective of the theme used.

The nice menu module by default creates some blocks in Drupal. You just have to edit the block called nice menu 1 & configure it & display in a specific region of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Bootstrap, and is very hard give you an answer without see what you have in your site, but maybe [Nice Menus](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) can be your solution.

Comment: I tried Nice Menus, Superfish and other similar modules, but i was only able to display the sub menu for the navigation menu. I think the theme is designed by default to show only parent items in the primary navigation section. 

Actually when i checked the theme structure there is no main-menu block,  so i added a new menu block to the header region and it work, the child item is now displaying, however all the styling is gone.

Comment: Did you tried add the same 'main menu' like secondary menu? That is, in admin/structure/menu/settings set 'Main menu' in source for both menu links.